# Google App Engine Python: Redirect to same page to reload table

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python

I have an html page where you enter the information in a form and when you click the submit button, it redirects the page and updates a table with the new information. I used "self.redirect('/')" and it did reload everything but did not update the table unless I manually refresh the page. Below is my code:

```
#Used to load up index.html    
class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    #HTML Get request to pull information from the datastore
    def get(self):
        title = "Video Game History"
        template_vars = {
            'title' : title, 'message' : "Enter the video game that you've played before..." }
        template = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template('index.html')
        self.response.out.write(template.render(template_vars))

        #Pulls info from the datastore and displays it
        self.query = MyGames.query()
        self.response.write("""
            <table>
                <caption>Game History</caption>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Description</th>
                        <th>Company</th>
                        <th>Console</th>
                        <th>Genre</th>
                        <th>Recommend</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>         

            """)
        for dbInfo in self.query:
            self.response.write("""
                <tr>
                    <td>%s</td>
                    <td>%s</td>
                    <td>%s</td>
                    <td>%s</td>
                    <td>%s</td>
                    <td>%s</td>
                </tr>
                """ % (dbInfo.name, dbInfo.description, dbInfo.company, dbInfo.console, dbInfo.genre, dbInfo.recommend))

        self.response.write("""
                </tbody>
            </table>
            """)


            #self.response.write('<p>%s</p>' % dbInfo.name)

    def post(self):
        gameName = self.request.get("gameName")
        gameDescription = self.request.get("gameDescription")
        gameCompany = self.request.get("company")
        gameConsole = self.request.get("console")
        gameGenre = self.request.get("genre")
        gameRecommend = self.request.get("recommend")
        #If gameRecommend is checked, mark yes. Otherwise, mark no.
        if gameRecommend == "Recommended":
            gameRecommend = "Yes"
        else:
            gameRecommend = "No"

        #Post the information into the datastore
        myGames = MyGames(
            name = gameName,
            description = gameDescription,
            company = gameCompany,
            console = gameConsole,
            genre = gameGenre,
            recommend = gameRecommend)
        myGames.put()
        self.redirect('/')
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the datastore's [Eventual Consistency](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/articles/balancing-strong-and-eventual-consistency-with-google-cloud-datastore/). Items added to the datastore may take a moment or so before they are visible to queries that aren't using their key directly. `MyGames.query()` in your case.